# Using constants in fxml layout

Tags: java, javafx, constants, fxml

In my FXML Project I don't want to hardcode all the constants in my layout. Simple things like margins and paddings. I'd prefer to keep them all in one place. How would I do that?

Can I create a class with constants and access them in my fxml layouts? I know about fx:define but I would have to repeat this in every fxml file. Or is there a way to fx:define in a central file and append this to all my fxml layouts? Or maybe there is something similar to resource bundles which I use for internalization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where it's possible I recommend using a CSS stylesheet.

There is no equivalent for all properties in css though. For those you could initialize the `FXMLLoader.namespace` map before calling load. The entries of the `namespace` can be used as if they were defined using the key of the entry as `fx:id`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));

    // initialize namespace
    Map<String, Object> namespace = loader.getNamespace();
    namespace.put("a", 10d);
    namespace.put("b", 20d);

    Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### test.fxml

```xml
<Pane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <Rectangle x="$a" y="10" width="20" height="20">
            <fill>
                <Color fx:constant="BLUE"/>
            </fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle x="$b" y="30" width="20" height="20">
            <fill>
                <Color fx:constant="RED"/>
            </fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </children>
</Pane>
```